# My pushback isn't working?

Tags: c++

my board cpp

```
#include "BBoard.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

User user_l;
BBoard::BBoard(){
    title = "Default BBoard";
    vector<User> user_list;
    User current_user;
    vector<Message> message_list;
}

BBoard::BBoard(const string &ttl){
    title = ttl;
}

void BBoard::setup(const string &input_file){
    ifstream fin;;
    fin.open(input_file.c_str());
    while(!fin.eof()){
        user_list.push_back(user_l);
    }
}

bool BBoard::user_exists(const string &name, const string &pass) const{
    User copy(name, pass);
    vector<User>::const_iterator i = 
        find(user_list.begin(), user_list.end(), copy);
    return !(i == user_list.end());
}

void BBoard::login(){
    string sn, pw;
    cout << "Welcome to " << title;
    bookmark:
    cout << "\nEnter your username ('Q' or 'q' to quit): ";
    getline(cin, sn);
    if((sn == "Q" || sn == "q")){
        cout << "Bye!";
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    getline(cin, pw);
    user_exists(sn, pw);
    if(user_exists(sn, pw) == false){
        cout << "Invalid Username or Password!" << endl;
        goto bookmark;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Welcome back " << sn << "!";
    }
}
```

and the header

```
#ifndef BBOARD_H
#define BBOARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class User
{
public:
    User() { }

    User(const std::string& _name, const std::string& _pass)
        : name(_name), pass(_pass)
    { }

    friend bool operator==(const User& lhs, const User& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.name == rhs.name) &&
               (lhs.pass == rhs.pass);
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string pass;
};
class Message{
};
class BBoard{
private:
    string title;
    vector<User> user_list;
    User current_user;
    vector<Message> message_list;
public:
    BBoard();
    BBoard(const string &ttl);
    void setup(const string &input_file);
    void login();
    void run();
private:
    //void add_user(istream &infile, const string &name, const string &pass);
    bool user_exists(const string &name, const string &pass) const;
    //User get_user(const string &name) const;
    //void display() const;
    //void add_message();
};

#endif
```

with main

```
#include "BBoard.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    BBoard board;
    string name;
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    name = argv[1];
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    cout << name << endl;
    board.setup(name);
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    board.login();
    cout << "Test" << endl;
}
```

for my program in main, I set up the prints to see where my program is not working and located it at board.setup(name).  I think that my pushback by reading stuff from a text file is not working as a result as it just keeps flashing an underscore for me in Visual Studio.  Have I set up the vector and pushback for it wrong?

Comment: When declaring class member variables, it's enough to declare them in the class. The declarations in the constructor for `BBoard` are just local variable declarations.

Comment: Unrelated advice: Don't put `using namespace` directives into headers. Try to avoid them almost everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in the `setup` function is that you don't actually *read* anything from the file. You just push an empty string in what will be an infinite loop.

---

Oh, and never do `while (!fin.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it. The reason is that the `eofbit` flag will not be set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of file.

I suggest you do e.g.

```
while (std::getline(fin, user_l))
    user_list.push_back(user_l);
```

Or possibly

```
while (fin >> user_l)
    user_list.push_back(user_l);
```

(Depending on the format of your file.)

Comment: I thought that I was passing in the name via my maincpp into the file?

Comment: @RikoKurahashi You need something like this: `fin >> user_1;` in your reading loop.